# Angular2 Material Tooltips - Class is not being added

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I have the following component.html:

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <span matTooltipClass="primary-tooltip" matTooltipPosition="above" matTooltipHideDelay="100000" matTooltip="{{cert.awsCertId}}"><p style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;max-width:120px">{{cert.awsCertId}}</p></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In my component.scss:

```
.primary-tooltip {
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: #FC5558;
}
```

As per the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api) this should add a custom class to the material tooltip but I don't see the styles being applied. Have I got it wrong? Is there any other way that I could apply styles to the tooltip?

Comment: As @yurzui said, you should place your style in a common style sheet, not in your component css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either place your style in a common style sheet

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axjz12-dto3dw?file=styles.css)**

or set `encapsulation` to `ViewEncapsulation.None` on your component:

```typescript
@Component({
 selector: '...',
 template: '...',
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
 styles: [`
   .primary-tooltip {
      min-width: 300px;
      background-color: #FC5558;
   }
`]
})
export class Component {}
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axjz12?file=app/tooltip-position-example.ts)**

Comment: Adding the style into a common scss worked. Could you explain more on that?

Comment: Angular adds prefix to styles that are declared within component metadata when encapsulation is Emulated(default)

Comment: Something like `.primary-tooltip[_ngcontent-c3]` But div that will have primary-tooltip is located out of component template and don't have `_ngcontent-c3` attribute

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the class direclty because it renders as a shadow dom. By using host you can the change the css for shadow dom

```
:host /deep/ .primary-tooltip {
 min-width: 300px;
  background-color: #FC5558;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is needed only if a component doesn't provide something similar to ngClass. But material tooltip provides `matTooltipClass` that we can use to apply styles.